# how can i make restful API in nodejs?

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, api

I want to create restful API in nodejs for my android application.But after watching so many videos and different patterns i'm bit confuse.Can anone guide me and show the complete roadmap to create APIs and how to deploy nodejs APIs on online server with mongoDB database. Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create restful APIs is using [express](https://expressjs.com/), they have great documentation and a begginner friendly [starting guide](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html). After you have a bit of experience with it the mongodb library to go is [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com) and they also have a [starting guide](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html). To learn how to combine and create a API with these I found a nice guide [here](https://www.djamware.com/post/58a91cdf80aca748640ce353/how-to-create-rest-api-easily-using-nodejs-expressjs-mongoosejs-and-mongodb).

Comment: What about the mongoDb in cloud and where to deploy the API to access API from online server. Can you tell me ?

Comment: There are a lot of services that provide Nodejs hosting like Heroku, Azure, AWS. Each one of them has a different way of deploying, you will need to stick to one and read their documentation on how to setup a database and deploy your api. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex answered the question on how to build a Restful API and communicate with a mongoDB database, I will explain how to deploy the application online. I would have done it in the comment section under Alex's post if only I had enough reputation.

If your looking for a free solution, have a look at [Heroku](https://heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs) which is really easy to use. They have a [starting guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs) as well to help you push your code online.

Heroku works with add-ons that can be plugged to your application. Every applications can be provided with add-ons, such as a database, to extend its functionalities. I suggest the [mLab MongoDB](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab) add-on which propose a free plan.

Comment: Indeed I've used Heroku and I can confirm that is easy and user friendly but I'm not really sure if it offers free mongodb hosting.

Comment: mLab has a free plan to test your app. Be aware that it is not suitable for production